# Ensuring right order using union all of unpivoted sub-queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, unpivot

I'm not sure how SQL might order the following query. Please note EDIT below.

Here is what the 3 tables look like:

Root:

```
ID  AuditID R1      R2      R3
1   1       Key1    Text1   20
```

Node:

```
ID  NodeID  N1  N2  N3
1   1       30  40  Text2
1   2       35  45  Text3
```

Leaf:

```
ID  NodeID  Metric  Value
1   1       L1      50
1   1       L2      60
1   1       L3      70
1   2       L1      80
1   2       L2      90
1   2       L3      100
```

I want my output to look like this in this order:

```
name    val
R1      Key1
R2      Text1
R3      20
N1      30
N2      40
N3      Text2
N1      35
N2      45
N3      Text3
L1      50
L2      60
L3      70
L1      80
L2      90
L3      100
```

I used the following code to get this format:

```
select name, val from(
        Select convert(nvarchar(max), runpvt.name) as name, runpvt.val from 
        (select convert(nvarchar(max), R1) as R1, 
         convert(nvarchar(max), R2) as R2, 
         convert(nvarchar(max), R3) as R3 from
         root
        ) root 
         UNPIVOT 

         (val for name in ([R1], [R2], [R3])) as runpvt

         union all

         select name, val from(
         select convert(nvarchar(max), nunpvt.name) as name, nunpvt.val from 
         (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID ASC) AS Row#,
         convert(nvarchar(max), N1) as N1, 
         convert(nvarchar(max), N2) as N2, 
         convert(nvarchar(max), N3) as N3 from
         node) node  
         UNPIVOT
         (val for name in (N1, N2, N3)) as nunpvt)tbl1

         union all

         select name, val from (
         select convert(nvarchar(max), l.Metric) as name, convert(nvarchar(max), l.Value) as val, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)  as ROW## from leaf as l)tbl2

    )dtbsvalues
```

Does the ordering by `row_number` ensure that I will always get the required order?

PLEASE NOTE EDIT:
I have added the following code. Can I be sure that N1,N2,N3 will be from 1st row and then N1,N2,N3 from 2nd row and so on?

```
Declare @leaf as int

Set @leaf = (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_catalog = 'trial'
   AND table_name = 'root')

Declare @node as int

Set @node = (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE table_catalog = 'trial' 
   AND table_name = 'node')   

            select name, val from(
                Select convert(nvarchar(max), runpvt.name) as name, runpvt.val, 1 as rid, 1 as filter from 
                (select convert(nvarchar(max), R1) as R1, 
                 convert(nvarchar(max), R2) as R2, 
                 convert(nvarchar(max), R3) as R3 from
                 root
                ) root 
                 UNPIVOT 

                 (val for name in ([R1], [R2], [R3])) as runpvt

                 union all

                 select name, val, rid, 1+@leaf as filter from(
                 select convert(nvarchar(max), nunpvt.name) as name, nunpvt.val, rid from 
                 (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)  as rid ,
                 convert(nvarchar(max), N1) as N1, 
                 convert(nvarchar(max), N2) as N2, 
                 convert(nvarchar(max), N3) as N3 from
                 node) node  
                 UNPIVOT
                 (val for name in (N1, N2, N3)) as nunpvt)tbl1


                 union all

                 select name, val, rid, 1+@node+@leaf as filter from (
                 select convert(nvarchar(max), l.Metric) as name, convert(nvarchar(max), l.Value) as val,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC)  as rid from leaf l)tbl2

            )dtbsvalues 

            order by filter, rid
```

Comment: @Nick submitted incomplete question by mistake. let me know if you need more. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you just want to unpivot the tables, combine the results, and order:

```
select name, val
from ((select v.name, v.val, r.id, 1 as which
       from root r cross apply
            (values ('R1', r.r1), ('R2', r.r2), ('R3', r.r3)) v(name, val)
      ) union all
      (select v.name, v.val, n.id, 2 as which
       from node n cross apply
            (values ('N1', n.n1), ('N2', n.n2), ('N3', n.n3)) v(name, val)
      ) union all
      (select l.metric, l.value, l.nodeid, 3 as which
       from leaf l
      )
     ) rnl
order by which, id, name;
```

You may need to cast the types of columns to strings.  It is unclear from the question what the underlying data types are.

Comment: the problem is that the column names might change & number of columns might increase also. i want it to be ordered by the column index of the tables and the order of the row index. does that make sense?

Comment: i have accomodated your suggestion. i am able to ensure that the order is always root, node & then leaf in long format. how can i tell however that node will be in right order? does the unpivot ensure that N1, N2,N3 will be from 1st row, and then N1, N2, N3 from 2nd row & so on?

Comment: @charliealpha . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  Tables have fixed sets of columns, they don't just "increase".  If you have a need for a  dynamic solution, then ask a new question.  As for ordering, your question is not at all clear and this should produce the result set you want.  I would suggest that if you have more specific requirements for ordering, then ask a new question.